# I want only admins to be able to use this command of my Discord.py bot

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

So I wrote a code for bulk message deletion but I want only the admins to be able to use this command.

```
import discord
import asyncio
from discord.ext.commands import Bot


class MyClient(discord.Client):

    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Logged on as', self.user)
        await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Game('NLRP with MaximaVoid'))

    async def on_message(self, message):
        
        # bulk deletion command

        if message.content.startswith('!ldlmsg'):
            await message.channel.purge()
        if message.content.startswith('!bdelmsg50'):
            delnum = 50
            await message.channel.purge(limit = delnum)
        if message.content.startswith('!bdelmsg10'):
            delnum = 10
            await message.channel.purge(limit = delnum)
```

Comment: I suggest you improve your question, add some examples, some code and make it more clear, Have a look here => [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way i did it in on_message:

```py
if message.author.guild_permissions.administrator == True:
```

If the message.author is an admin on the guild/server it returns true, if not it returns false.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following decorators:

```py
@commands.is_owner()  # If you only want the owner to execute this command
```

If there's a role named `Admin` or `Administrator` or something similar:

```py
@commands.has_role('Admin')  # Anyone who executes the command must have the 'Admin' role to continue
```

If you want people with any of the specified roles to be able to execute the command:

```py
@commands.has_any_role('Admin', 'Administrator')  # You can add as many roles as you want
```

Finally, if you want only people with 'Administrator' permissions to be able to execute this command:

```py
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True, ban_members=True)  # You can add as many permissions as you would like
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure if you are reffering to "admin" as in a Role named Admin or if that is the bot owner.

If it is the bot owner, you can add the decorator:

```
@commands.is_owner()
```

In case it is a role named Admin, you can use the decorator:

```
@commands.has_role("Admin")
```

The correct way to do your code would be to separe it in different functions, instead of checking all commands in `on_message`. You should read the discord.py documentation:
https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/cogs.html?highlight=cogs